# Using MSBuild to sign ClickOnce or assembly results in error MSB3321

Tags: .net, msbuild, clickonce, code-signing

I've set up my simple project in Visual Studio 2008 to use a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) installer. I've specified that the ClickOnce manifests should be signed by our comapny's [PFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Certificate_filename_extensions) file. When I set this up in Visual Studio it asked for the password for the PFX file, which I gladly supplied. Everything works fine when I build and publish from within Visual Studio. It also works fine building from [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) on my machine.

However, when I try to build it using MSBuild on our build machine, I get the following error:

```
ERROR MSB3321 in 
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(1805,7)
    : Importing key file "ourCertificate.pfx" was canceled (sic).
```

After some searching I've found a little bit of information that says this is because I haven't supplied the password. But I can't find a way to supply the password on the build machine. I've also seen suggestions to install Visual Studio, and supply the password once inside Visual Studio, and then it will work from MSBuild after that. But I'd really like to avoid installing Visual Studio on the build machine.

I've tried double clicking the PFX file to import it and putting in the password when asked, but this didn't help.

This same thing happens if I check 'Sign the assembly' in Visual Studio and supply the same PFX file.

How can I fix this problem? Is there a manual way of storing the password on the build machine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you import your certificate into your Trusted Publisher store on the build machine?
(Internet Explorer > Tools > Options > Content > Certificates)

I don't use MSBuild to create deployments; I use Mage.  However, I use our .pfx file to import our cert into my Trusted Publisher store.  In order to do that I have to input the password.  After that's done, when I save a manifest in Mage I no longer have to provide a password. I can simply select the cert from my store.

Comment: Importing the certificate into my Trusted Publisher store worked for me.

Comment: In addition to that I had to use this msbuild property to instruct msbuild to sign the ClickOnce application:     **ManifestCertificateThumbprint**   [...this helped me](http://huntjason.wordpress.com/2009/10/22/publishing-clickonce-applications-to-run-side-by-side-for-different-environments-from-the-command-line-using-nant/)

Answer (score 0):

John Robbins has a blog post about how to wrap [SignTool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild), *[Code Signing – It’s Cheaper and Easier than You Thought](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/12/21/code-signing-it-s-cheaper-and-easier-than-you-thought.aspx)*.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.