# VSTS Online - Build Solution With ClickOnce Signing PFX Password

Tags: wpf, azure-devops, clickonce, pfx

I have a WPF Solution I am building in VSTS Online.

Below is my basic Build Definition:

[image]

In Visual Studio 2017 locally I've assigned a Click Once Certification (PFX). Everything builds and compiles fine locally.

[image]

The Build fails with the following error:

> Cannot import the following key file: . The key file may be password
>   protected. To correct this, try to import the certificate again or
>   import the certificate manually into the current user's personal
>   certificate store.

What setting/step do I need to include to ensure the PFX file is seen and the password is set?

Answer (score 3):

Using this code to import certificate file (PowerShell task):

```
$pfxpath = 'pathtoees.pfx'
$password = 'password'

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

Related thread: [Visual studio team services deploymen/buildt certificate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547231/visual-studio-team-services-deploymen-buildt-certificate-error)

Comment: What value should be used for $password?  I have tried the certificate password and my account password. both give Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The specified network password is not correct."

Comment: Should be certificate password.

Comment: Is this not a security risk? Won't the certificate be imported on a shared machine, including it's private key?

Comment: I am running this as a part of Azure DevOps build pipeline as a power shell script task. The task completes without error but my build fails saying Cannot import the following key file: Image1.pfx. The key file may be password protected. 
To correct this, try to import the certificate again or manually install the certificate to the Strong Name CSP with the 
following key container name: VS_KEY_60E41B07B11F3C7E

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT not working for me. i am still getting same error message as  stuart said.

Comment: @Stuart did you find the reason and solution for your problem?