# Import PFX password-protected certificate to be used during build process

Tags: uwp, azure-devops, pfx

Would it be possible to have more explanation on how to use certificate for UWP app in Azure DevOps, the certificate being supposed to be handled at build time?

So far, I use Secure Files, then use tasks Download Secure File and Copy Files to upload it in my UWP project.
The problem is that, as the certificate is password-protected, the build fails.

Could you please indicate how to handle the password ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS Online - Build Solution With ClickOnce Signing PFX Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48692240/vsts-online-build-solution-with-clickonce-signing-pfx-password)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw this post but I don't want to install the certificate on the build agent machine. And as mentioned by others, the script doesn't work, even when providing the certificate password, raising the same error messages