# How to Install dotnet dev-certs certificate on a CI Server

Tags: .net, certificate, azure-pipelines, dotnet-cli, dotnet-dev-certs

I would like to run my API using `dotnet run`, so I can run some tests against it. However, on Azure Pipelines and AppVeyor, they don't have a developer certificate installed and I get an error when I try to start my API. Installing a developer certificate involes running:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

However, this shows a dialogue which the user has to click and this fails the build. How can I install the developer certificate on a CI server?

Comment: For Azure pipelines you can use [secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops)

Comment: How about using the approach mentioned in this? https://superuser.com/questions/191038/installing-deleting-root-certificate-without-certmgr-certutil-asking-the-end-u and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4196997/certificate-install-security-warning-workaround

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either use your own certificate (aspnet core `listenOptions.UseHttps(new X509Certificate2(...));`)  in your app or export the dotnet dev certificate with:

```
dotnet dev-certs https --export-path <path> [--password <pass>]
```

This generates the certificate that you need.
You can trust this certificate manually with powershell as explained here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49444664/1216595
or
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001534/1216595