# Nuget package restore error in VSTS build

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have created one build definition for one of csproj as below.

[image]

I am getting nuget restore related error in build process with this definition, can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

**[Update]**

As per suggestion provided in comment I have updated to "**\*.sln" then it has worked but i am getting errors as below

[image]

Comment: Did you try to put the .sln file instead of "packages.config"?

Comment: As i put .sln it's succeed but error in build solution task for all assembly in that csproj. like  Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'log4net' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk It has worked but not i am getting few other errors , please see my updated question

Comment: Are you using host build agent or your own agent, suggest you also add system.debug=true in your variable to get more detail log info for troubleshooting.

Comment: host build , will check with debug= true

Answer (score 0):

For the new issue, add a powershell script task in your build definition to import the certification.

```
$pfxpath = 'pathtoees.pfx'
$password = 'password'

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Security
$cert = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$cert.Import($pfxpath, $password, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]"PersistKeySet")
$store = new-object system.security.cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -argumentlist "MY", CurrentUser
$store.Open([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.OpenFlags]"ReadWrite")
$store.Add($cert)
$store.Close()
```

Refer to this question for details: [Visual studio team services deploymen/buildt certificate error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43547231/visual-studio-team-services-deploymen-buildt-certificate-error/43623773#43623773)